# VBA - Copy a row multiple times based on the number of occurrence of a field in a different table

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck with a logic to implement in a VBA Code. I have two tables in two different worksheets & I want to join them based on column which will occur multiple times in both the sheets.

I have attached a screenshot of my need.  Please help me!
Thanks in advance.
I am trying to replicate the table here, not sure if this would come good.

```
>|===================|====================|===========================|
>| Table 1           |     Table 2        |        Result             |
>|===================|====================|===========================| 
>| Fruit  |  Store   |   Fruit  | Buyer   | Buyer | Fruit  |    Store |
>|===================|====================|===========================|
>| Apples | Walmart  |  Apples  | Rita    | Rita  | Apples |Walmart   |
>--------------------|--------------------|---------------------------|
>| Apples | Target   |  Grapes  | Rita    | Rita  | Apples |Target    |
>--------------------|--------------------|---------------------------|
>| Grapes | Walmart  |  Grapes  | Peter   | Rita  | Grapes |Walmart   |
>--------------------|--------------------|---------------------------|
>| Grapes | Target   |  Oranges | Rita    | Rita  | Grapes |Target    |
>--------------------|--------------------|---------------------------|
>| Oranges| Walmart  |  Oranges | Peter   | Rita  | Oranges|Walmart   |
>--------------------|--------------------|---------------------------|
>| Oranges| Target   |  Oranges | Tom     | Rita  | Oranges|Target    |
>|===================|====================|---------------------------|
>                                         | Peter | Grapes |Walmart   |
>                                         |---------------------------|  
>                                         | Peter | Grapes |Target    |
>                                         |---------------------------| 
>                                         | Peter | Oranges|Walmart   |
>                                         |---------------------------| 
>                                         | Peter | Oranges|Target    |
>                                         |---------------------------| 
>                                         | Tom   | Oranges|Walmart   |
>                                         |---------------------------| 
>                                         | Tom   | Oranges|Target    |
>                                         |===========================| 
>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: could you add a description of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Comment: What you are proposing is a perfect application for a relational database. Is there any particular reason you feel you need to do this in Excel VBA instead of MS-Access or another RDB program?

Comment: [This seems very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657541/excel-merge-two-excel-tables-based-on-matching-data-in-columns) to what you are trying to achieve. Granted that's with functions, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Banged this out quickly on a few hours sleep, seemed to work ok.

```
Sub Combine()

    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Populate with source sheet used
    'may need to add a second ws and change array reading below
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'populate with where you want data to go
    'may want to change to a listobject and the writes below accordingly
    iDestRow = 2

'Read both tables into arrays
    aTable1 = wsSrc.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    aTable2 = wsSrc.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange

'Cycle through each buyer and populate new dataset
    For i = LBound(aTable2) To UBound(aTable2)
        sBuyer = aTable2(i, 2)
        sFruit = aTable2(i, 1)
        For j = LBound(aTable1) To UBound(aTable1)
            'if the buyer exists in table 2 and table 1 populate destination
            If aTable1(j, 1) = sFruit Then
                wsDest.Cells(iDestRow, 2) = sBuyer
                wsDest.Cells(iDestRow, 3) = sFruit
                wsDest.Cells(iDestRow, 4) = aTable1(j, 2)
                iDestRow = iDestRow + 1
            End If
        Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I used the idea to run two for loops and place the content on the destination to arrive at my needs. Thanks a lot!