# Regex: Merge two similar strings

Tags: regex, string, atom-editor

inside Atom text editor in two separate file I have two series of strings:

```
group1:
 "Name1, Surname1, Book1, year1"
 "Name2, Surname2, Book2, year2"
 "Name3, Surname3, Book3, year3"
   ... (and so on)

group2:
 "Surname1, Book1, year1"
 "Surname2, Book2, year2"
 "Surname3, Book3, year3"
   ... (and so on)
```

The second serie of strings is the same of the first, expect that has no name parameter, only the surname. How can I merge by similarity (same surname) the first into the second series of strings? 
I imagine the logic to be something like this:

```
IF x string in group1 contains "surname1" and string y in group2 contains "surname1" THEN merge x string with y string.
```

is there a way to do it with regex? 
Thanks

EDIT:
For merge i mean this:
z string= "Name1, Surname1, Book1, Year1" where Name1 comes from x string.
I know it seems not logical, but I have a bibliography, where group2 is in alphabetical order, and group1 is not, so that's why I want them to merge.

Comment: this is not a job for regex. A simple way to fix this is to write some script / code that extacts this csv data and merges conditionally. If you don't want to write code, I'm pretty sure you can do this in excel / LibreOffice (https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657541/merge-two-excel-tables-based-on-matching-data-in-columns

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm new to Regex and I hoped to find a magic formula :-D without coding. I guess I'll write some python script, or just do it myself in an old fashioned way.